# C# Round to list values

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

I'm trying to round a result value to the next number in a list.

If the value is (187) I need to set the result to (240)

```
int[] list = new int[] { 16, 25, 35, 50, 70, 95, 120, 150, 185, 240, 300, 400 };
double max;
max = list.Where(x => x <= result).Max();
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're close:

```
list.Where(x => x >= result).Min();
```

Answer (score 4):

You just want the first item greater than or equal to your expected result:

```
var max = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x >= result)
```

NOTE: This assumes the list is ordered, as your example seems to suggest.

If you want to get an exception if there's no match then just use `First`:

```
var max = list.First(x => x >= result)
```

Comment: That is assuming the list is ordered. I mean, it is, in the example. But nowhere stated explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Try using [List.BinarySearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8).

> Returns the zero-based index of item in the sorted List, if item is found; otherwise, a negative number that is the bitwise complement of the index of the next element that is larger than item or, if there is no larger element, the bitwise complement of Count.

```
var list = new List<int> { 16, 25, 35, 50, 70, 95, 120, 150, 185, 240, 300, 400 };

int index = list.BinarySearch(result);
int rounded;
if (index < 0)
{
    if (~index == list.Count)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Number is too big.");
    }
    rounded = list[~index];
}
else
{
    rounded = list[index];
}
```

The asymptotic complexity of this method is `O(log n)`, where `n` is the length of the list, whereas the complexity of `Where`/`First` is `O(n)`, which probably won't matter in your case, but is still good to know.

Comment: Assuming the list is ordered, this is a pretty neat solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round upwards, you can find which value in the list subtracted by your value is greater than or equal to 0.

```
max = list
    .OrderBy(x => x) // Can be skipped if list is ordered.
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x - value >= 0) // if "value" is 187, max will be 240.
```

Ensure you have something that handles if the "max" value is null.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are _also_ assuming the list is ordered. I mean, it is, in the example. But nowhere stated explicitly. Just a heads-up.

Comment: @RobIII - Good catch! Made the necessary adjustment. But @D Stanley's answer is the simplest and the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the closest value

```cs
var list = new List<int> { 16, 25, 35, 50, 70, 95, 120, 150, 185, 240, 300, 400 };
int value = 187;
var nearestValue = (from v in list
        let  d = Math.Abs(value - v)
        orderby d
        select v)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: So for the value = 187 the closest value is 185

Comment: I suggest to update the query to solve the original task: 187 -> 240.
`from v in list
            let d = v - value
   where d > 0
            orderby d
            select v`